# How to bulk-import all Power Query workbook connections into PowerPivot?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, powerpivot, powerquery, powerbi

Within PowerPivot for Excel, under the 'Design' tab, there's an option to use 'Existing Connections' as a data source for Power Pivot. Here we can select our carefully shaped & managed Power Query connections (e.g. to SQL Server, Web pages, flat files).

However this interface only permits the selection of a single Workbook Connection at a time for import. I'd like to select multiple/all Power Query connections.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific bulk-import requested cannot be performed in the standard Excel 2010 and PowerBI interface at this time.

Edit: It's now possible to avoid the necessity of bulk-importing your Power Queries into PowerPivot, by creating the connections directly. See blog at: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/04/29/load-power-query-directly-to-power-pivot-in-excel-2010/

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013 you can refresh all the Power Query connections by using the Refresh All option on the DATA ribbon.   You can also do the same on the Power View ribbon using the Refresh All option that's located there.

[image: Excel 2013 with Power Query Refresh All on Data Ribbon]

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)

Comment: Unfortunately my organisation is still on office 2010, perhaps the behaviour I'm attempting to describe is different with the proper data model in 2013... 
The Power Query data sets are not available/visible to the PowerPivot model in 2010. Except via manual one-by-one import process as described in my question. I was wondering if there was a bulk import option but it seems as though the answer is No (in 2010).

Answer (score 0):

Tom, there doesn't seem to be a way to select multiple connections in that dialogue box.

You can however refresh **all** sources from the home tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jacob. But unfortunately refreshing all Power Pivot data sources doesn't achieve the initial import from Power Query

Comment: sorry. missed the Power Query reference. Don't totally understand the question as don't you 'load' the PowerQuery once you have done the initial creation?

Comment: So we've created a series of Power Queries which are present as connections within the Workbook. I'd like to make the results of these queries available within the Power Pivot window for building Pivot Tables. We can do this but only one connection at a time rather than all at once. Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way? I may try to just use PP not PQ for accessing simple data sources...

Comment: @TomSqlDev There isn't a way to do this in bulk. Are the power queries located in the same file as the PowerPivot model?

Comment: @guitarthrower Thanks for the answer, I believe you're correct (at least through the standard GUI). Yes they're in the same Excel2010.xlsx. Excel2013's data model may have helped